# Setting Azure Blob Index tags with parenthesis - works in Browser but not in REST API

Tags: xml, azure, http, blob, storage

I have been trying to set some blob tags and receiving a horrible error:

> Response: HTTP/1.1 400 The tags specified are invalid. It contains characters that are not permitted.

I can set the tags with the same value in container browser without any issue, but via REST api it always fails with parenthesis, I have tried encoding in several ways, but the only way to success is to omit the patenthesis (which I am currently doing).

Successful payload:

```html
<Tags>
    <TagSet>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileID</Key>
            <Value>307145362</Value>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileName</Key>
            <Value>/omit/gkcs2022-11-15 14.49.12.log</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>FileType</Key>
            <Value>GKCS Log File</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DeviceID</Key>
            <Value>151283</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>Timestamp</Key>
            <Value>2023-01-20T144920.192Z</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DOWNLOADEDTO_GBMSVINTELLIFS</Key>
            <Value>False</Value>
        </Tag>
    </TagSet>
</Tags>
```

Failing Payloads:

Raw:

```html
<Tags>
    <TagSet>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileID</Key>
            <Value>307145362</Value>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileName</Key>
            <Value>/omitted/gkcs(2022-11-15 14.49.12).log</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>FileType</Key>
            <Value>GKCS Log File</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DeviceID</Key>
            <Value>151283</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>Timestamp</Key>
            <Value>2023-01-20T144920.192Z</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DOWNLOADEDTO_GBMSVINTELLIFS</Key>
            <Value>False</Value>
        </Tag>
    </TagSet>
</Tags>
```

URL Encoding:

```html
<Tags>
    <TagSet>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileID</Key>
            <Value>307145362</Value>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileName</Key>
            <Value>/omit/gkcs%282022-11-15 14.49.12%29.log</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>FileType</Key>
            <Value>GKCS Log File</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DeviceID</Key>
            <Value>151283</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>Timestamp</Key>
            <Value>2023-01-20T144920.192Z</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DOWNLOADEDTO_GBMSVINTELLIFS</Key>
            <Value>False</Value>
        </Tag>
    </TagSet>
</Tags>
```

Escape Character:

```html
<Tags>
    <TagSet>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileID</Key>
            <Value>307145362</Value>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>FileName</Key>
            <Value>/omit/gkcs\(2022-11-15 14.49.12\(.log</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>FileType</Key>
            <Value>GKCS Log File</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DeviceID</Key>
            <Value>151283</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>Timestamp</Key>
            <Value>2023-01-20T144920.192Z</Value>
        </Tag>
         <Tag>
            <Key>DOWNLOADEDTO_GBMSVINTELLIFS</Key>
            <Value>False</Value>
        </Tag>
    </TagSet>
</Tags>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Azure Storage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tags#request-body), only the following characters can be used in valid tag keys and values:

> - Lowercase and uppercase letters (a-z, A-Z)
> - Digits (0-9)
> - A space ( )
> - Plus (+), minus (-), period (.), solidus (/), colon (:), equals (=), and underscore (_)

Unfortunately, parenthesis characters are not currently supported by the `Set Blob Tags` REST API request.

Comment: Thanks - I assumed I must be doing something wrong as this worked fine in Browser - how rubbish that different constraints apply in the REST api. We also had some issues with the Python libraries which surprises me greatly as I would expect this to be pretty rock solid.